# How to calculate the amount of memory occupied by the variable in Pascal?

Tags: variables, memory, pascal

I need to calculate the amount of memory that any variable takes. Thanx for any input.

EDITED: I didn't notice that I need to **calculate it manually (by hand)**. Thanx

Comment: What do you mean with "calculate it manually"? You can use sizeof() on types as well as on variables, even compound variables like records or arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SizeOf(variable)
```

of course that only goes for the variable not to any additional memory the variable might point to, or any alignment if it is part of a structured type.